# Why does Jacob tie his bed sheets to the bars in his bathroom window?

Tags: plot-explanation, shot-caller

In [*Shot Caller* (2017)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4633690/), the main character, Jacob/Money, wants to leave his home but, because he is being watched by a parole officer, doesn't exit through the main door but the bathroom window.

He does this by busting open the barred window, climbing out and placing the bars back in place so as not to be conspicuous, but not before **he rips and fashions bed sheet into a rope, which he then uses to tie the bars in the bathroom window to the toilet**.

[image] [image][image] [image]

If I recall correctly, the reasoning behind this isn't referenced later in the movie, and if it is, I missed it. I presume it has to do with throwing off the parole officer, in some way, but it remains a mystery to me.

### Why does he fashion this bed sheet/rope contraption to tie the bars in the window to the toilet in the bathroom?

Comment: Didn't he use it to climb down to ground level?

Comment: @JohnnyBones No. The house is [ground floor level](http://i.imgur.com/FwVEpeh.jpg), and he [jumps out of the window](http://i.imgur.com/2gQdVRb.jpg) onto the street curb and turns around to put the bars back in the windows and tie the knot.

Comment: I haven't seen this movie myself, but I'm guessing he was tying down the (now broken) bars so that they wouldn't fall out of the window while he was gone.  He had to rig this up to something *inside* the house so that the parole officer wouldn't see the sheet-ropes from the outside if he was peeking around the corner.

Answer (score 1):

I watched this last night, and my conclusion was that the director/writer was most likely leading the viewer to believe that Jacob was going to hang himself.  He had just had a very emotional discussion with his son, and there was a scene in the beginning of the movie in which an inmate hung himself.

Using the bedsheet afterwards as a means to secure the bars to the window was a bit of a cop out, I think.  There really was no point in it, he could have just as easily placed the bars inside the bathroom and closed the window.  Anyone walking past it would have questioned why a sheet was wrapped around it and then noticed the broken concrete around the brackets that secured the bars to the building.  If someone wanted to break in, they could have just cut the sheet or untied it, so it wasn't meant to keep out intruders.  The only conclusion I can come to is that you were supposed to think he was going to commit suicide, but then they had to actually do something with that sheet.